# QSqlDatabase not connecting

Tags: sql, qt

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.
I am trying to write to database.db in my computer but it doesn't work.

```
QString dbName = "/home/mustafa/Desktop/Programlama/QC/Flash_Cards/database.db";
QSqlDatabase con = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE", dbName);
con.setUserName(dbName);
if(!con.open()){
    qDebug() << "failed";
}else{
    qDebug() << "ok";
}
QSqlQuery query(con);
con.commit();
bool ok = query.exec("CREATE TABLE ltable (name TEXT, num INT)");
qDebug() << ok;
con.commit();
con.close();
```

it shows that connection has opened, and query is executed just fine. But when I check the database.db file, it is empty. It is like as if it makes a temporary database, despite the fact that I give it a valid file in a valid path.

I did exactly what youtube tutorials said, but theirs work and mine doesn't. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your setHostName is what you really want?  But, try setting the Database Name as follows:

```
QString dbName = "/home/mustafa/Desktop/Programlama/QC/Flash_Cards/database.db";
QSqlDatabase con = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
con.setDatabaseName(dbName);
con.setHostName(dbName);
if(!con.open()){
    qDebug() << "failed";
}else{
    qDebug() << "ok";
}
QSqlQuery query(con);
con.commit();
bool ok = query.exec("CREATE TABLE ltable (name TEXT, num INT)");
qDebug() << ok;
con.commit();
con.close();
```

Your version didn't create the .db file for me, but the above compiles and runs on Ubuntu 20.04, QT 5.12 and the db is viewable in SQLite Browser.